# How to read canary value in gdb?

Tags: gdb

In a program I am debugging, the canary value is read to `eax` from `gs:0x14` memory location. I am attaching gdb to the process late enough to break on the `mov` reading the canary to `eax`. Therefore, reading `eax` is not an option to me. How can I read (`x/w`) the canary location (`gs:0x14`) in gdb?

Comment: very similar questions have been asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354063/how-to-use-a-logical-address-in-gdb) and [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1828881.html)

Comment: @SYS_V I'm not sure either one was really "answered" (well, maybe if you count "you can't" as an answer)

Answer (score 3):

It seems it's not possible to do this using built-in GDB functionality but I found a blog post which explains how to get the `gs` base from a core dump:

https://www.technovelty.org/linux/debugging-__thead-variables-from-coredumps.html

You should be able to generate a core using `generate-core-file` command then inspect it outside of GDB.

Comment: Ah! I see. Every time I learn something new from you. Thanks. Will try that.